# WebSocket security?

Tags: websocket

I have a custom websockets server (non-secure) implemented with of libuv. Same server also supports some HTTP requests ([source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/inspector_socket_server.cc)).

Everything works just fine if I listen on 127.0.0.1, except some users are reporting that they can't connect from remote systems. HTTP requests work fine if I listen on 0.0.0.0 but browsers and VS Code do not seem to even try to send Upgrade request. What could be the reason? Could it be my workstation setup (e.g. some sort of a firewall)?

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with my corp network settings - works just fine in other networks...